# App name in shared facebook post need to navigate to facebook page

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I want to navigate from app name to facebook page. 
I shared post from my android app.

Location of app name

In developers.facebook I tried with add platform and have option to add web site, but can't add facebook link to fb page. 
Is there way to do this?
Only solution that comes to my mind is to add url to some website address and that address redirects to facebook page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I decided to create goo.gl short link to my facebook page.

Maybe it isn't best solution but surely work.